# Reference error- is not defined trying to deploy smart contract

Tags: deployment, smartcontracts, erc20

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract in form of ERC token on truffle local blockchain and it brings up an error, I don't know why.
The code of deploy using java script (test file):

```
const Dodgi = artifacts.require("Dodgi")

contract("Dodgi", (accounts) => {

    before(async () => {
        Dodgi = await Dodgi.deployed()
    })
    is("gives the owner 1 mil tokens", async () => {
        let balance = await Dodgi.balanceOf(accounts[0])
    })
})
```

smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Dodgi is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 _supply) ERC20("Dodgi", "DGL") {
        _mint(msg.sender, _supply * (10**decimals()));
    }
}
```